# Вызов метода модели из partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть такая структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `_kurators.html.erb` пытаюсь отрендерить партиал:

```
<%= render :partial => 'kurators/simple_list' %>
```

В `kurators/simple_list` пытаюсь вызвать метод модели:

```
<%= get_issues_by_me %>
```

Модель `kurator.rb`:

```
class Kurator < ActiveRecord::Base
    def get_issues_by_me
       'test'
    end
end
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
undefined local variable or method `get_issues_by_me' for #<#<Class:0x00000004146988>:0x00000004257278>
```

Что я делаю не так?

UPDATE:
`kurators_helper.html.erb`:

```
module KuratorsHelper
  def kurators_helper_test
    'test'
  end
end
```

Comment: А как вы узнали, что `get_issues_by_me` это метод модели в контексте вьюхи?

Comment: Попробывал еще добавлять название модели `<%= Kurator.get_issues_by_me %>`, но в таком случае получаю ошибку: `undefined method get_issues_by_me for Kurator(Table doesnt exist):Class`. Да, это верно, у меня нет таблицы, но она мне и не нужна, мне нужно просто вернуть данные из этого метода

Comment: Попробуйте объявить метод, как метод класса, а не метод экземпляра: `def self.get_issues_by_me`

Comment: Да, это сработало. А как из партиала можно вызвать метод хелпера?

Comment: Поскольку хелперы обычно включаются в контекст вьюхи, то просто по голому имени, как вы изначально ошибочно сделали для модели. Это для моделей такой способ не работает, а для хелперов -- вполне.

Comment: @D-side, попытался вызвать метод хелпера `<%=kurators_helper_test%>`, получаю ошибку: `undefined local variable or method kurators_helper_test for #<#<Class:0x00000003f6a498>:0x00000003fa45a8> `. Содержимое хелпера привел в вопросе.

Comment: А должно работать. Скорее всего, у вас застрял старый код и нужно перезапустить приложение.

Comment: @D-side, в хелпере перед названием метода добавил `self` и только так заработало

Comment: Это не норма.`self` в объявлении нужен только при вызове с явным указанием модуля, а-ля `Модуль.метод`. Для хелперов это традиционно (по меньшей мере в Rails 3 и 4, и об изменениях в 5 я не слышал) не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Kurator < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.get_issues_by_me
       'test'
    end
end
```

И вызывайте вот так

```
<%= Kurator.get_issues_by_me %>
```

Если надо для какого то конкретного пользователя вызвать, то прочитайте про скоупы:

http://rusrails.ru/active-record-query-interface#scopes